# WP Custom Fields, hide code if field is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a custom field template plugin for WP. I want to hide

```
<li>Sqft: [squareft]</li>
```

if the field is empty. I've tried different codes, these are two I've tried based on suggestions:

```
<?php if ('squareft' !== '') { ?><li>Sqft: [squareft]</li>  
<?php } ?>
```

And

```
<?PHP $squareft = ('squareft'); if ($squareft != '') { echo '<li>Sqft: [squareft]
</li>';}  if (empty($squareft)) { echo " "; }  ?>
```

I obviously don't have a clue what I'm doing, although I'm learning through trial and error. It uses shortcodes, so [squareft] is what to use to output the field data.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: 
I think I've got it working, based on doing this method. Not yet gone live but it's working in my test post.

```
<?php
global $post;
$bathrooms = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bathrooms', true);
if ( !empty($bathrooms) ) { echo '<li>Baths: [bathrooms]</li> | ' ; }
?>
```

Comment: i think you should be able to test using if `(get_post_custom_values("squareleft", $post_id) !== '')`

Comment: post_id i believe can be retrieved with `$post_id = get_the_ID();'

Comment: Like I said, I don't have a clue what I'm doing and don't understand what to do with the code you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using the get custom fields plugin I have used the following to hide content if the field it empty (in this case the 'info' field):

```
<?php $info = c2c_get_custom('Info');?>
<?php if ( $info == "" ) {echo "";} else {echo "<h2 id=comments>Notes</h2><div id=info>$info</div>" ;} ?>
```

Not sure if this will help but it might give someone else more ideas.

Are tring this :

```
<?php if ( (c2c_get_custom('image')) ) { ?>
blah blah blah php code etc...
<?php } ?>
```

Works perfectly. If field has something it shows, if not no show, it was leaving a broken image when empty, now its good.

Comment: aha!
<?php if ( (c2c_get_custom('image')) ) { ?>
blah blah blah php code etc...
<?php } ?>

Works perfectly. If field has something it shows, if not no show, it was leaving a broken image when empty, now its good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replacement of the `if` statement in your first code sample):

```
<?php if (do_shortcode('[squareft]') != '') { ?>
    <li>Sqft: [squareft]</li>  
<?php } ?>
```

Or if you know the custom meta field's actual field name (generated by the plugin, probably some kind of prefix + squareft) you can do:

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'squareft', true) != '') { ?>
```

It would help to know the specific plugin you are using.

Comment: It's called Custom Field Template.

Comment: Ennui, tried the do_shortcode, it does not hide the text when the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'squareft', true) != '') { echo "display output";?>
```